# Can you help to remove the file not found exception error in android?

Tags: android, file, error-handling, assets

Code to remove error in android studio

[image: Code to remove error in android studio]

Comment: post error in the logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your photo, you are using the wrong method.

You should place assignmenttitle.docx to **/res/raw** should not to **/assets**.

Since the file is within your application, you shouldn't use "file:///android_asset/assignmenttitle.docx".

This means the file path to Android Device storage, not the application's resource.

Instead, you should use like this!

```
Uri uri= Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() +
                    "/raw/assignmenttitle.docx");
```

or

```
InputStream ins = context.get().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.assignmenttitle.docx);
```

Comment: InputStream is working. Thank you

Comment: Hi bro, if my answer is useful for you, please accept my answer.